# Spresense AIを２つ同時に使うことはできますか

Tags: spresense

```
DNNRT dnnrt;
DNNRT dnnrt2;
```

２つ目の `DNNRT` の `bigin()` にてエラーになります。

Answer (score 1):

確かに DNNRT のインスタンスを二つ作るのは出来ないようですね。リソースの問題でしょう。ですが、DNNRTをシーケンシャルに使うことはできるようです。次のようなコードを使って実際に試してみました。

```
/* trial of 1st neural network */ 
dnnrt.begin("model.nnb");
DNNVariable input(size);
   ...snip...
dnnrt.inputVariable(input, 0);
dnnrt.forward();
DNNVariable output = dnnrt.outputVariable(0);
   ...snip...
dnnrt.end();

/* trial of 2nd neural network */ 
dnnrt.begin("model2.nnb");
   ...snip...
dnnrt.inputVariable(input, 0); /* input data は使いまわし */
dnnrt.forward();
output = dnnrt.outputVariable(0);
   ...snip...
dnnrt.end();
```

こちらのほうが少ないメモリを有効に使えますし、試してみてはいかがでしょう？